# Who are "Lizard people"?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

At Apex cybernetics, Bernie, who was hiding, saw two Apex employees was crossing
the corridor, then he whispers to Madison and Josh:

> Bernie: Follow me. **Lizard people** build all their facilities the same
> way. I can find the exit.

Who are "Lizard people"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bernie is a conspiracy theorist Podcaster.

Lizard people is a reference to the real world conspiracy theory that world leaders are reptile aliens popularized by David Icke.
See
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptilian_conspiracy_theory

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that there isn't any evidence of them in the film and the line was likely to make the character seem foolish